# How to package other another build with your conda build

Tags: python, conda, pypi, conda-build

I'm creating a build for my PyPI package with

```
> conda skeleton pypi myPackage
> conda build --python 3.5 myPackage
```

and I get the following error:

```
BUILD START: myPackage-py33_0
updating index in: /data/anaconda2/conda-bld/linux-64
updating index in: /data/anaconda2/conda-bld/noarch
Can't build /home/user/myPackage due to unsatisfiable dependencies:
Package missing in current linux-64 channels:
  - mysqlclient
```

So I built mysqlclient from PyPI which allowed me to successfully build `myPackage`:

```
> conda skeleton pypi mysqlclient
> conda build --python 3.5 mysqlclient
```

I then start my new conda env and try to install my package

```
> conda install -c wwbp myPackage
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .
PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Dependency missing in current linux-64 channels:
  - myPackage 1.0.dev24* -> mysqlclient

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda mysqlclient
```

I then have to install mysqlclient first and then myPackage

```
> conda install -c bioconda mysqlclient
> conda install -c wwbp myPackage
```

Is there a way to include this build of mysqlclient with myPackage? I would like to be able to install it with one install call.

Comment: You just have to upload your mysqlclient package to the same channel that myPackage is uploaded to. Then `conda install` will (should) find the dependency in the same channel.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. You should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to upload your `mysqlclient` package to the same channel that `myPackage` is uploaded to. Then `conda install -c mychannel myPackage` will (should) find the dependency in the same channel.